# Save iPhone Photo Library Path to a Plist

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview, plist

I want to save an image path string for a particular photo from the main iphone photo library  in a plist file.

So that later I can call the plist image path string in a web view and see the photo.

I know I need the absolute path which is probably a similar path to the documents directory but:

1.) How do I get the photo name of the particular photo?

2.) Do I need to append the absolute path string to the photo name and then write to the plist?

3.) Will the path change for every install of my app - which would make a hard coded absolute path impossible to use?

Any pros want to tackle this conundrum?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an app targeting lower than iOS4.0, then you may use [UIImagePickerController Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). This will let user pick one image from the phone album, which then, you can save in your app's documents directory and save the corresponding link in the info.plist file. The documents directory gets deleted when your app gets uninstalled, and so you lose the path as well.

A better way, with a disadvantage of restricting this feature (and so your app if its a main feature) to only iOS4.0 and above, would be using [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Each photo in the iphone is represented by a unique URL that you can save, and you can refer to a particular image using that url. There is a nice [tutorial blog](http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/) that can help you get started with it.

Now, in your question, you are talking about a **particular** photo. You can not just know of any **particular** photo in the library, unless you let the user pick one. This brings me to answer your last question. The URL is constant for that particular image (till the iphone is reset), but unless you have any way of keeping that information between *every* install of your app (what exactly do mean here?), I don't know how being a unique URL is going to help you here.

EDIT:
Just saw the tag of sdk 4.0 there, please ignore the first case (the <4.0 part).

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I want to use the UIImagePickerController!

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.iconPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.iconPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    self.iconPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    self.iconPicker.delegate = self;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    iconImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (IBAction)save {

    [plist.data setValue:iconImage.image forKey:@"Icon"];
    [plist.data writeToFile:plist.file atomically:YES];

    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

How do I save the image name of the edited image in plist string.

I know I don't want to save the CGImage data or whatever because of the load size.

I think I can pass an xcode variable into HTML through putting all my HTML into string objects and then adding variables to the objects where I need includes...

So I can create a path to the photo directory but I need to know how to get the name of the saved edited image from UIImagePickerController???

Comment: There is no name for an edited image, it is a temp file. You can however save this image to your directory as a file and name it yourself. Then you can refer it by that name. On a different note, you should not save the image data in your plist file, since the data can be very large and it not advised to put large data in the plist file.